# How to display data received from serial port in a textbox without the text disappearing in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, serial-port

So, I'm trying to develop a simple application in visual C# which gets data from serial port and displays it in a textbox (to monitor temperature). I'm acquiring and displaying the data successfully, using the DataReceived event to update a global string variable and a timer to update the text field on my text box, as shown:

```
    private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            globalVar.updateTemp = port.ReadLine(); //This is my global string
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tempDisplayBox.Text = globalVar.updateTemp; //This is my textbox updating
    }
```

The only issue I have is that the value shown in the textbox keeps flashing, making it hard to read. My timer is set to trigger every 10 ms (which should be fast enough, right?). Is there any way to make it more stable? I realize this may be a newb question, but to be fair I am a newb :) Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: i think 10ms is too fast, it's updating the text 100 times per second. You don't need it to be that frequent, try 100 ms

Comment: are you on winforms, WPF, ...???

Comment: winforms :) sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for the answers! I found a way to work around this issue:
Instead of replacing the contents of my textbox by rewriting the TextBox.Text property - which, as HenningNT implied, refreshes the control and causes the flickering - I'm now using the TextBox.AppendText method. Though, as I want to display only one line of data at a time, I use the textbox in multiline mode and the Environment.NewLine to jump to a new line before appending the text. As for the method of updating, I've gone back to using the timer because with the invoke method was crashing my application when I close the form, for some reason. Also, enabling double buffering didn't do me much good, although I guess I was doing it wrong... It still flickers a bit, but it's much better now :) I know this is not really a perfect solution (much more of a workaround), so I'll keep looking for it. If I find it, I'll be sure to update it here ;) My code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Timer to update textbox
    {
        if (tempDisplayBox.Text != globalVar.updateTemp) //Only update if temperature is different
        {
            try
            {
                tempDisplayBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                tempDisplayBox.AppendText(globalVar.updateTemp);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            { 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing to watch out for - I believe this will cause the text box to consume more and more memory as the program runs, since the text stored in it grows without bound.

Comment: @dsolimano: You are correct. You think that if I rewrite the TextBox.Text property periodically I could prevent this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need it updating every `10ms`? What about every `500 ms` or if not that then `100ms`. `100ms` will require your update method run 10 times less and therefore update 10 times less. The flickering you are expiriencing is due to the refresh speed. You could create custom method which will only update the temp only when target `Label` or `textBox` value is different than source `port`. But that will only sort the flickering when temp is steady, when temp will start vary it will bring back the flickering. Good luck ;-)

**UPDATE**

Hi I tried to reproduce the conditions and could not make my textbox nor Label flash. The way I tested it was by assigning `int ntick = 0;` and then increment the `++ntick;` inside of the `timer_tick` method. The results didn't make any of the controls flash and were updated even every milisecond at some point. I also tried string.Format to put some load on the method. Is your app responsive?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) Indeed I don't need it updating every 10 ms, but the flickering is still present with 500 ms, it's just slower. I mean, the text still disappears :(

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use double buffering. This way the operating system will redraw the Control off-screen, and only show the control when it is fully redrawn.

I have had the same problem, and solved it by extending the TextBox control like this:

```
public FastLogBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _logBoxText = new StringBuilder(150000);

        timer1.Interval = 20;
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Start();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_timeToClear)
        {
            _logBoxText.Clear();
            _timeToClear = false;
        }

        if (_logQueue.Count <= 0) return;

        while (!_logQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string element;
            if (!_logQueue.TryDequeue(out element)) continue;
            {
                _logBoxText.Insert(0, element + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        if (_logBoxText.Length > 150000)
        {
            _logBoxText.Remove(150000, _logBoxText.Length - 150001);
        }
        Text = _logBoxText.ToString();
    }
    public new void Clear()
    {
        _timeToClear = true;
        while (!_logQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string element;
            _logQueue.TryDequeue(out element);
        }
    }
    public void AddToQueue(string message)
    {
        _logQueue.Enqueue(message);
    }
}
```

I also use a timer and a concurrentQueue to avoid using Invoke to update the control from another thread. I also use a StringBuilder to prepare the string before putting it into the TextBox. StringBuilder is faster when building larger strings.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up double buffering on Google and this might work. Now to understand about extending controls and how to apply it to my code :) If it works I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadExisting()` to read the whole data at a time.
You need to handle `DataReceived` Event of `SerialPort`

```
serialPort1.ReadExisting();
```

**Sample:**

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
           String myData=serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        }
```

**Example Code:** Here i would like to show you the code to Read Data(RFID Tag Code which is basically of length 12)

```
        String macid  = "";
        private void DoWork()
        {
            Invoke(
                  new SetTextDeleg(machineExe ),
                  new object[] { macid  });
            macid  = "";
        }
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            string str1;
            macid += serialPort1.ReadExisting();

            if (macid.Length == 12)
            {
                macid = macid.Substring(0, 10);
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
                t.Start();
            }
        }

         public void machineExe(string text)
          {
            TextBox1.Text=text;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I am handling the DataReceived event, but the ReadExisting() method still gives me flickering.

Comment: @user3008375: if you use ReadExisting() it will give you complete data so that you can Set the Text at a time without need of a timer.

Comment: @user3008375: are you able to do that? otherwise i will add sample code to explain it.

Comment: You mean using the invoke method? It gives me the flickering as well and for some reason my application crashes when I close the form :/

Comment: @user3008375: check my edited Answer to get the Data Length of 12 characters.. you can modify as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but still the same flickering :/ Maybe the solution from HenningNT is the way to go? Only thing is I have to learn how to extend my textbox winform control properly to enable double buffering.

Comment: @user3008375: Okay Good Luck :)