# Retain the value from the Textbox

Tags: vb.net

Good Day! I'm having problem in retaining the data from textbox. It disappears for few seconds after tapping the RFID card. I'm using serialport to connect the arduino+rfid. I'm having difficulties on timer1 manipulation.

i tried changing the interval time for timer1 but it affects only on the delay of reading the card.

here the code by the way:

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
        rfidd.Text = receivedData

    End Sub
```

the value from recievedData to rfidd.text will not reset to " "

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution in C#
here's the link:
[How to display data received from serial port in a textbox without the text disappearing in Visual Studio C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069756/how-to-display-data-received-from-serial-port-in-a-textbox-without-the-text-disa)

i did little changes on the code to VB can understand:

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
        ' rfidd.Text = receivedData


        If (rfidd.Text IsNot receivedData) Then ' Only Then Update If temperature Is different

            Try

                rfidd.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
                rfidd.AppendText(receivedData)

            Catch ex As NullReferenceException

            End Try


        End If


    End Sub
```